# extract current location only works in my phone

Tags: java, android

The code works in my phone properly but doesn't works sometime. Also, this code doesn't work in other phone properly. I have tried many times. And while sending this app's apk file through xender the installation fails. Please help to improve my code so that it works properly in all phone when location is turned ON.

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView result;
Double latitude, longitude;
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addressList;
Getgps gps;
Context mContext;

protected LocationManager locationManager;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abcd);

    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    mContext = this;


    try
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (isGPSEnabled)
        {
            getlonglat();   //check location

            if(CheckInternetConnection(MainActivity.this)) {
                getaddress();
                // getlocation
                if(result.getText().toString().matches(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Poor Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turn ON Your Location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showgpsSettingsAlert();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));


            Toast.makeText(mContext, " after delay khatey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void getlonglat() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "GPS Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        gps = new Getgps(mContext, MainActivity.this);
        // Check if GPS enabled
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLatitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}


public void getaddress() {
    try {
        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

        String address = addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        String area = addressList.get(0).getLocality();
        String city = addressList.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalcode = addressList.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String fullAddress = address + ", " + area + ", " + city + ", " + country + ", " + postalcode;
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Internet Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        result.setText(fullAddress);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static boolean CheckInternetConnection(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
    }
    return false;
}

public void showgpsSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Setting");
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK          ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel                                         ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sorry we cannot proceed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();// Showing Alert Message
}
}
```

Getgps.java

```
package com.example.bibash28.locationfinal2;

/**
 * Created by Bibash28 on 11/3/2017.
 */

public class Getgps extends Service
{

private Context mContext; // Flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false; // Flag for network status
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location;  // Location

Double latitude,longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1000;// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;// 10 meters// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds// 1 minute

Activity activity;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public Getgps(Context context, Activity activity)
{
    this.mContext = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation()
{
    try
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
        this.canGetLocation = true;
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (location == null) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,

                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&

                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 50);

                } else {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, mLocationListener);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;
}



private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};

//Function to get latitude
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;
}


//  Function to get longitude
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    return longitude;
}

//Function to check GPS/Wi-Fi enabled   @return boolean

public boolean canGetLocation()
{
    return this.canGetLocation;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: please make sure you suggest the correct answer.

Comment: "please make sure you suggest the correct answer." What does that mean? Are you testing us?

Comment: No Sir. I have found that some people just paste the link which make no sense at all. Sorry that was not for you. Please help me if you can.

Comment: You want the user location, which is a critical information. How do you manage the permission? And what are the version of Android you're testing the app with? (As the permission system has changed with Marshmallow (API 23))

Comment: I am testing in Marshmallow device.. But I want this to work in all android devices. Permission is asked with pop up message.

Comment: How it doesnt works? Exceptions? Notice that GPS may take long to aswner a FINE_LOCATION (more if it was turned off for long)

Comment: I don't know. I am totally unaware. I have considered 10 sec delay. But this program is not working in other phones. This works fine on my phone. But sometimes I have to try many times to get current location. This is creating problem for my semester project. Please help.